DENEB Gantt Chart and Additional Columns
After additional research, it seems like in order to have additional fields added to the DENEB, a new Template is required.
I added the code to the Specification to show a new Column "Importance" but nothing shows as a part of the Ganntt Chart Visual.
{
      "name": "ImportanceColumnWidth",
      "value": 55
    },

Could someone direct me to the right path to create a new Template from DENEB and add the new Column.

Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You're expected to show some code.
